# List indices must be integers, not str

Tags: php, python, list

I am trying to do something like the code below in Python

**PHP Code:**

```
if(!$my_data[$n_vertex]['visited']){       
     $my_data[$n_vertex-1]['visited'] = true;
}
```

What i am exactly doing in **Python**

```
def bfs(my_data):
      my_queue = [] #array to store vertices
      my_queue.insert(0, my_data[0]); #pass the first value to the first index of queue
      my_data[0]['visited'] = 'true';
      while my_queue:
                vertex = my_queue.pop()


      for n_vertex in vertex['neighbors']:
                #print(n_vertex)

                if my_data[n_vertex]['visited']:
                          continue
                else:
                          my_data[n_vertex]['visited'] = 'true'
                          my_queue.insert(0, my_data[n_vertex]);
```

And i am getting the following **error**:

```
 File "/Users/osamayawar/Desktop/Python/BFS.py", line 30, in bfs
 if my_data[n_vertex]['visited']:
 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What exactly it means by list indices must be integers.

**Note:** bfs is my function name

Comment: What is `my_data`? What is `n_vertex`?

Comment: Added the complete function now - It may help

Comment: @JeffCraine: PHP's array type is not like Python's list type. You need to use both lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, list indices is always integer. You access the item by using the index:

```
l = ['a', 1, 2]
print l[0] ## 'a'
print l[1] ## 1
```

What you probably want is a `dict`:

```
d = {'vertex': 120}
print d['vertex'] #120
```

Comment: yes i need a dictionary. I have pasted my code below. I do not know how to get it as it is inside the loop

for n_vertex in vertex['neighbors']:
                    #print(n_vertex)
          
                    if my_data[n_vertex]['visited']:
                              continue
                    else:
                              my_data[n_vertex]['visited'] = 'true'
                              my_queue.insert(0, my_data[n_vertex]);

Comment: @JeffCraine Please update the question and show us what the data structure is like.

Answer (score 1):

Python list indices must be integers. PHP uses key-value pairs for accessing items in an array and may have duplicates. For example:

```
$array= array( "name" => "Bill", "job" => "programmer",
                0 => "Bill",
                1 => "programmer");
```

PHP arrays are more similar to Python dictionaries. See [Python standard library docs on dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

It would be helpful to see your data you're working with. (The value of `my_data`)

If you had a data structure that looked similar to this, which is a list of dictionaries, it could work:

```
my_data=[{"visited":False, "some_other_key":"string-value"},
         {"visited":True, "some_other_key":"string-value"}
        ]
```

You may want to re-write your python code as follows to make it more "pythonic".

```
if not my_data[n_vertex]['visited']:
    my_data[n_vertex]['visited'] = True
    my_queue.insert(0, my_data[n_vertex])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a string as a list index:

```
my_data[n_vertex]['visited']
```

'visited' isn't a number.

Could you include your declaration of my_data please?

Comment: visited is true and false - used as boolean. my_data is actually reading a file having data in which visited is either false or true.

Comment: Then, as you have probably been made aware, you need to use the dictionary structure.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace reports, `my_data[n_vertex]` is a `list`. You can't access a `list` by a `non-integer` index. You can access it by an index in the range [0, length - 1], for example.

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"] # 3 elements
print list1[0] 
print list1[1]
print list1[2] # length - 1
```

You may want to [read more about lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

**Note** that in Python, [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can be accessed by any immutable type (`str`, `int`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

It means that `my_data[n_vertex]` resolves into a list, and you're trying to access one of it's items through a string key, when lists only accept integer subscripts.

If you add the following line into your program:

```
print type(my_data[n_vertex])
```

it will print `<type 'list'>`.

There's probably an error in your code that creates the `my_data` object.
You probably want the items on `my_data` to be [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)s instead of lists.